# bouncycastle AlgorithmIdentifier class is not found

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle

I am new to bouncycastle, I was trying to use `AlgorithmIdentifier` to sign a cert. But I am not able to find the  `AlgorithmIdentifier` in the jar file.

Maven dependency I added is,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error : `The import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier cannot be resolved`

how can i fix it?

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce this error. Who tells you this error - the compiler or the IDE? If IDE - what do you use?